# Why many Linux distros use setuid instead of capabilities?

Tags: linux, linux-capabilities, suid

`capabilities(7)` are a great way for not giving all root privileges to a process and AFAIK can be used instead of `setuid(2)`. According to [this](https://linux-audit.com/linux-capabilities-101/) and many others,

> "Unfortunately, still many binaries have the `setuid` bit set, while they should be replaced with `capabilities` instead."

As a simple example, on Ubuntu,

```
$ ls -l `which ping`
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 44168 May  8  2014 /bin/ping
```

As you know, setting suid/guid on a file, changes the effective user ID to root. So if there the suid-enabled program contains a flaw, the non-privileged user can break-out and become the equivalent of the root user.

My question is why many Linux distributions still use `setuid` method while setting `capabilities` can be used instead with less security concerns?

Comment: Because capabilities are relatively new.

Comment: And there are more pressing things to do that update all the setuid programs.

Comment: My relevant manpage (2018) says there is no standard governing  `capabilities`.

Comment: @Roadowl that's completely irrelevant. There's no standard which says that a `ping` utility (or some other setuid program) should exist at all, much less whether it has to or should be setuid (instead of other mechanism) in order to function properly.

Comment: RHEL since the 7 release have minimised the use of setuid in preference of capabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not give the *reason why* some dudes somewhere decided one way or another, but some auditing tools and interfaces may not yet know about capabilities.

An example is the [proc_connector](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9f46080c41d5f3f7c00b4e169ba4b0b2865258bf) netlink interface and the programs based on it (like [`forkstat`](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ecking/forkstat/)): there are events for a process changing its credentials, but not for it changing its capabilities.

---

FWIW, the cause why *you* may not get eg a `net_raw+ep` `ping(8)` instead of a setuid one on a Debian-like distro is because that depends on the `setcap(8)` utility from the `libcap2-bin` package already existing *before* you install `ping`. From `iputils-ping.postinst`:

```
    if command -v setcap > /dev/null; then
        if setcap cap_net_raw+ep /bin/ping; then
            chmod u-s /bin/ping
        else
            echo "Setcap failed on /bin/ping, falling back to setuid" >&2
            chmod u+s /bin/ping
        fi
    else
        echo "Setcap is not installed, falling back to setuid" >&2
        chmod u+s /bin/ping
    fi
```

---

Also notice that `ping` itself will drop any setuid privileges and switch to use capabilities on Linux upon starting, so your concerns about it may be a bit exagerated. From `ping.c`:

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct addrinfo hints = { .ai_family = AF_UNSPEC, .ai_protocol = IPPROTO
_UDP, .ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM, .ai_flags = getaddrinfo_flags };
        struct addrinfo *result, *ai;
        int status;
        int ch;
        socket_st sock4 = { .fd = -1 };
        socket_st sock6 = { .fd = -1 };
        char *target;

        limit_capabilities();
```

From `ping_common.c`

```
void limit_capabilities(void)
{
        ...
        if (setuid(getuid()) < 0) {
                perror("setuid");
                exit(-1);
        }
```

Comment: Of course on Ubuntu 16.04, iputils Version: 3:20121221-5ubuntu2 package never uses the setcap method:
` # Don't use setcap for Ubuntu as tarballs don't properly store those by default. LP: #1302192 `
Taken from _postinst_ script.

Comment: I think that `setuid()` call can be made to fail to drop privilege using securebits: SECURE_NO_SETUID_FIXUP.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a different planet were capabilites patches were rejected, the submitter had to try harder to make a neighborly improvement, and came up with this:

- filesystems can be mounted suid, nosuid, or capsuid.
- if mounted capsuid, setuid bits on ${file} don't count unless .${file}.suid_capability also exists, is setuid, and is either 0-length or parseable in some standardized format:

  ```
  -r-sr-xr-x. 1 carton carton 3812 Dec 27 15:39 t1
  -r-Sr--r--. 1 carton carton    0 Dec 27 15:39 .t1.suid_capability
  ```
- if the file is empty, setuid bit works as normal. If it has parseable contents, it works as partial-root capabilities.
- if desired the .t1.suid_capability files can be annotated with fields for:

  - binding to a hash of their matching 't1' file
  - binding to an absolute path, so for example a setuid file within a chroot does not become "hot" until you chroot into it.
  - binding to a public key or hash nonce loaded at boot identifying the installed system like a uuid.  If the private key or nonce is hidden from a backup server, traditional password resets would still work but some forms of rootkit persistence would become more difficult.  It also lets you work with images of other systems in subdirectories, automatically making them effectively "nosuid"-mounted even if you are undisciplined about mount options and elect not to use the absolute path feature.

Now answer some questions about this planet relative to our own:

- any missing functionality compared to our native planet?
- which system works better with 'ls', 'tar', 'rsync', 'cpio', 'find', 'pax', 'mtree'?  with gentoo's ebuild sandbox?  with LXC?
- which system works better with diskless or guest systems running on NFS or 9p roots?
- which system works better with tripwire?

Now repeat those questions considering three systems instead of two:

- our planet:  mysterious capabilities metadata in filesystems
- alternate planet using civilized Unix approach
- mosvy's 'ping' example, where the binary drops privileges right after it starts

With the third system are finally starting to lose features relative to status quo:  Someone could write a hypothetical capabilities-aware tripwire that works less well in the 'ping' example.  Has anyone done that, though?  . . . anyone outside NSA---have the people forcing this complexity on us done that work to deliver (relatively small) value from the complexity?  And if that's the feature-hill we want to die on (as opposed to reducing attack surface), is there maybe a better way to get it, like dm-verity, that once again moots the complexity?

Now let's make a slight refinement to mosvy's 'ping':

- `crt.o` or some early runtime startup code reads the sidecar file and `/etc/suid_capability_hash_nonce`.  It drops suid if `/etc/suid_capability_hash_nonce` exists but the sidecar file does not (in "alternate planet" terms, the existence of `/etc/suid_capability_hash_nonce` makes the whole system '-o capsuid'-mounted).  The early runtime startup code handles parsing the sidecars and dropping to the enumerated capabilities so that logic doesn't have to be coded into main.c one-by-one.

Honestly, I think the 'ping' example is superior because programs know what capabilities they need, and the need changes only when the program's source code changes.  By setting them in a drop_privileges()-style function the need will never get out of sync.  Fanned-out distributions won't have to scramble to update capability sets.

If you disagree and want the sidecar/capabilities-style system, something equivalent could have been implemented without tampering with kernel, mount options, bootup, any of it:  old dracut-nfsroot initrds would keep working.  It is just a matter of style.

This is all a Socratic way of saying capabilities offers nothing beyond dm-verity + 'ping'-style privileges-dropping.  There is nothing "unfortunate" about eschewing complexity that's not pulling its weight.

Every few years CADT developers invent some new form of metadata to cram into filesystem directories:  Finder metadata, POSIX ACLs, SELinux contexts, NFS ACLs.  What will they think of next?  How long will it take to update all the filesystems, all the network protocols, all the fileutils tools, all the non-Linux storage operating systems, all the fancy licensed "enterprise" tape backup suites?  Will anyone ever get around to updating all that stuff, or will we just limp along with substandard tools?  Will even the core feature be documented usefully, or will it be the undocumented plaything of a few annoying "distributions"?  Will the feature work most of the time, but stop systems from booting unexpectedly and create chicken-and-egg recovery problems?  Will the feature actually stop any attacks?

Is it fair to all the people who have to clean up after them and tolerate complexity in their own systems that made different, simpler choices, just to unbreak interop that their new feature broke?

The value delivered is particularly low in this case, but we have enough experience to set the value bar high on this type of proposal.  I think it was a mistake to accept the feature into Linux and applaud any distribution that avoids it.

Answer (score 0):

Capability support was really enabled in 2008 when file capabilities were added to the kernel. So, that's 13 years and counting to replace *setuid*. Your question is very valid.

If capability support wasn't implemented in a backwardly compatible way in Linux, it would either have been rejected at birth, **or** things would have surely changed by now! I suspect it all comes down to the fact that there is no economic incentive to adopt them when their benefit is only evident *temporarily* when a bug in some code is found to be exploitable.

I think that people are resigned to all the ways that setuid binaries seem to be exploitable and the point fixes that people quickly roll out when another vulnerability surfaces. Buffer overflow -> launch shell -> root exploit -> code fix -> start over. They are comfortable with the idea that user identity = privilege (ie., root). This spills into how people want to describe the futility of breaking down all powerful root into [independent capabilities](https://blog.sevagas.com/IMG/pdf/exploiting_capabilities_the_dark_side.pdf), when a chain of exploits can yield all privilege. Clearly, the pervasive idea that privilege and identity *should* be equivalent is why Ambient capabilities even exist.

Capabilities, however, when used as they were intended to be used are **not** identity = privilege. They are *capable binaries* = privilege - where the privilege is reduced relative to a user identity executing arbitrary code, by the **combination** of those capability bits and the code in the actual program that has them.

If you write code that edits files, it is clear it shouldn't need to worry about being directly abused for raw ethernet packet formation, or loading kernel modules. Exploiting a bug in that code may well allow a malicious edit of a file but, unlike setuid, it won't allow strange packets to be sent on the network. At least not without tricking the code of some independently capable executable into doing it by proxy.

However, no one intentionally writes buggy code, so I think the answer to your question comes down to another question: "where exactly is the benefit of limiting how exploitable an exploit is?".

I suspect that if some distribution were to figure out how to restructure their code base to eliminate setuid-root binaries, in favor of file capabilities, it would fare better (certainly no worse) over time as code exploits are found vs. other distributions clinging to setuid-root. But, until such a distribution comes into being, I can't fault the idea that that is just an opinion.

Comment: > no one intentionally writes buggy code,
But working with the least privilege a known good practice anyway?